# C# unity script to take and save screenshot in android gallery with library UnityNativeGallery

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Actually I am trying to take a screenshot and save it into the Android gallery, I am using a opensource library for this purpose "Unity Native Gallery" my code is following:

```
NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.CheckPermission();
if (permission == NativeGallery.Permission.Granted) {
     Debug.Log("May proceed");
 }
else {
     Debug.Log("Not allowed");
}
// Output ==> "May Proceed"

Debug.Log("Path is "+NativeGallery.GetSavePath("GalleryTest","My_img_{0}.png"));
//Output ==>  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/GalleryTest/My_img_1.png

Texture2D ss = new Texture2D( Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
ss.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height ), 0, 0 );
ss.Apply();

Debug.Log("Secondlast");
permission = NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery( ss, "GalleryTest", "My_img_{0}.png" ) ;

Debug.Log("Done screenshot");
```

but my it never save the screenshot, when i see the console, I get 2 important logs

1.My Debug log "SecondLast" was print on the console but not the last one "Done screenshot"

2.There is an exception printed "UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/GalleryTest/My_img_1.png" is denied."

Important point :- I already already set the Write permissions to External (SDCard) in unity player settings. (actually I try with both settings "Internal" and "External")

Comment: I believe you need to request those permissions before you try to use them.  Just because you set it in the Unity Player Settings doesn't mean the person playing the game gave you permission.  Also you only told us what 1 of the log messages where what was the first?

Comment: Sorry to miss the first output, now I update the question. as the output is "May Proceed".

Comment: @eddge actually NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery() method internally call the RequestPermission method. but as you said we have to ask the permission, but I never see any dialogue to ask permission for gallery.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at their repo, with the source code you have provided, it seems you are trying to take the screenshot and save it regardless of if you have permission or not.  This may be your issue:

```
NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.CheckPermission();
if (permission == NativeGallery.Permission.Granted) 
{
     Debug.Log("May proceed");
}
else 
{
     Debug.Log("Not allowed");
     // You do not break out of the function here so it will attempt to save anyways
}
```

You should probably have it look like this:

```
NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.CheckPermission();
if (permission == NativeGallery.Permission.ShouldAsk) 
{
     permission = NativeGallery.RequestPermission();
     Debug.Log("Asking");
}
// If we weren't denied but told to ask, this will handle the case if the user denied it.
// otherwise if it was denied then we return and do not attempt to save the screenshot
if (permission == NativeGallery.Permission.Denied) 
{
     Debug.Log("Not allowed");
     return;
}
Debug.Log("Path is "+NativeGallery.GetSavePath("GalleryTest","My_img_{0}.png"));
//Output ==>  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/GalleryTest/My_img_1.png

Texture2D ss = new Texture2D( Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false );
ss.ReadPixels( new Rect( 0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height ), 0, 0 );
ss.Apply();

Debug.Log("Secondlast");
permission = NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery( ss, "GalleryTest", "My_img_{0}.png" ) ;

Debug.Log("Done screenshot");
```

Comment: thanks brother for your quick reply, actually NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery() method internally call this RequestPermission method.